# Multi domains one magento install

Tags: magento

Morning

I have read multiple threads concerning this subject changed my .htaccess and index.php multiple times yet cannot seem to get it to work.

This is the code in my index.php file

```
/* ORIGINAL */
/* Store or website code */
/* $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : ''; */
/* Run store or run website */
/* $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] :     'store'; */
/* Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType); */

/* ADJUSTED */
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {

/* 2nd Website */
case 'www.walkingdeadgraphicnovels.co.uk/shop/':
case 'www.walkingdeadgraphicnovels.co.uk/shop/':
Mage::run('www.walkingdeadgraphicnovels.co.uk/shop/', 'walking_dead_graphic_novels');
break;

/* main website */
default:
Mage::run();
break;
```

This is my .htaccess code

```
# A Place in Space
SetEnvIf Host *aplaceinspace.co.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host *aplaceinspace.co.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

# Walking Dead Graphic Novels
SetEnvIf Host *walkingdeadgraphicnovels.co.uk/shop/            MAGE_RUN_CODE=walking_dead_graphic_novels
SetEnvIf Host *walkingdeadgraphicnovels.co.uk/shop/ MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please elaborate how your shop behaves now. Did you configure the urls in the admin configuration, too? Did you use the URL as store code? Mage::run() expects a store or website code, not a URL.

Comment: Hi

I followed numerous tutorials. I basically have a few domains that I want to run through one magento, so aplaceinspace.co.uk covers all, and walkingdeadgraphicnovels goes to another root category and has different layouts and menus.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this in your htaccess:

```
# A Place in Space
SetEnvIf Host aplaceinspace\.co\.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host aplaceinspace\.co\.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

# Walking Dead Graphic Novels
SetEnvIf Host walkingdeadgraphicnovels\.co\.uk MAGE_RUN_CODE=walking_dead_graphic_novels
SetEnvIf Host walkingdeadgraphicnovels\.co\.uk MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

And use the original block in the index.php